# data in my outputfile didn't print all result it should have

Tags: python, list, return, lxml

I am trying to output the index of makeList[start] to makeList[end]. I have all the correct start and end values, which are about 11 pairs total. However, I dont get the correct output because it doesn't print out all the possible output. Why is that happening?

```
def searchPFAM(fname):
   with open(fname,'rb') as f:
       root = etree.parse(f)
       for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='PFAM']/lcn"):
          try:
             start = int(lcn.get("start"))
             end = int(lcn.get("end"))
             yield start, end
          except (TypeError , ValueError) as e:
             pass 

uniprotID ='Q14591'

def createRef():
    fileInput = open(uniprotID +'.txt','r')
    readAA = fileInput.read()
    store_value = (readAA.partition('\n'))
    aaSequence = store_value[2].replace('\n', '')
    makeList = list(aaSequence)
    return makeList

makeList = createRef()

for start, end in searchPFAM(fname):
    print start, end  
    if start <= end:
        with open('newfile.txt','w') as fileinput:
            while start <= end:
                result = makeList[start]
                fileinput.write(result)
                start += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but you probably want:

```
with open('newfile.txt','w') as fileinput:
    for start, end in searchPFAM(fname):
        print start, end  
        if start <= end:
            while start <= end:
                result = makeList[start]
                fileinput.write(result)
                start += 1
```

Your old version only writes 1 start/end loop to the file, closes it and then opens a newfile (with the same name as the old one), writes 1 start/end loop, closes the file ... In other words, you're re-writing the file with each loop iteration.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.  Sometimes these simple things are sitting there staring you in the face and they're so hard to see/track.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason: You need to flush the output file before the script terminates.

snippet from above:

```
with open('newfile.txt','w') as fileinput:
        while start <= end:
            result = makeList[start]
            fileinput.write(result)
            start += 1
fileinput.flush()
```

Comment: He's using `with` so the file should automagically close (and get flushed) when that block is exited

Comment: @Levon and it does... `fileinput` strangely remains in scope, but is in fact a closed fileobj, so any operations fail

Comment: I got the error message when i put flush() in saying: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @Levon so right duh.  @ChadD It does stay in scope as the with clause does not limit the "new" var to the with scope just as python `if` and `for` syntaxes don't

Comment: @PhilCooper I don't really get what do you mean? how do i fix that btw?

Comment: The var fileinput is still in the `locals()` scope and will not fall out of scope until the current function or method returns (after which it will be garbage collected).  If it is in `global()` as it would be if your code above is a script, it will be garbage collected when the program terminates.  This is not a problem as @Lovon pointed out the file is properly flushed and closed at the end of the with clause.